# Is f(U(*)()) just a specialized version of f(U*)?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

When reading a wiki page, I found this sample code

```
template <class T>
struct is_pointer
{
  template <class U>
  static char is_ptr(U *); #1

  template <class X, class Y>
  static char is_ptr(Y X::*);

  template <class U>
  static char is_ptr(U (*)()); #2

  static double is_ptr(...);

  static T t;
  enum { value = sizeof(is_ptr(t)) == sizeof(char) };
};
```

To me, #2 is just a specialized version of #1, so it seems superfluous.

Did I make something wrong? What would it be like in the eyes of C++ compilers?

Comment: Not a specialization, an *overload*.

Comment: `U *` is a pointer to an `U` object. `U (*)()` is a pointer to a non-member function without arguments that returns `U` by value.

Comment: *"#2 is just a specialization of #1"* -> *"#2 is (an overload) more specialized than #1"*

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my wording. Question updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To me, #2 is just a specialization of #1, so it seems superfluous.

An overload, not a specialization. And yes, it is superfluous. In a template accepting `U*` for a parameter, `U` can resolve to an entire function type. It's what makes `is_pointer<int(*)(char)>::value` be true, despite the fact `int(*)(char)` **will not** match the overload #2.

> Did I make something wrong?

Since you did not make this code yourself, I don't believe you did. You correctly surmised there's a redundancy.

> What would it be like in the eyes of C++ compilers?

It would be an overload that gets picked for the specific case of checking a function pointer type that accepts no arguments. It conveys no interesting information compared to the `U*` overload, and can be removed.

It's possible this implementation was added to get around a compiler bug (where said function pointer types were not correctly handled). Modern compilers handle said function pointers correctly even if the superfluous overload is removed.

Comment: "get around a compiler bug" could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: @HuFellan - Elaborate on what?

Comment: You mentioned that the superfluous code might be added to get around a compiler bug. Could you provide some more details?

Comment: @HuFellan - Not really. It's speculation, not some bug I can point out to you. I have at times added superfluous elements to work around compiler quirks, hence the speculation.

Answer (score 3):

`template <class U> static char is_ptr(U *);`: `is_ptr` is a function taking a pointer to `U` (without a name) and returning a `char`.

`template <class U> static char is_ptr(U (*)());`: `is_ptr` is a function taking a function pointer (without a name), which gets no parameters and returns a `U`, and returns a `char`.

So, one gets a pointer to a `U` and the other a function pointer, which returns a `U`.

Comment: Question are: is `#2` superfluous? Can `Ret (*) ()` bind to `U*`?

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, I posit that, but also wonder there might be some other considerations involved?